# how to add empty lines in textarea

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm making my own little cms. I'm using an textarea filled with the database data. now I want to know if there is a way to get empty lines. to work with 
paragraphs. for example:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
>>this line empty<<
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

now the user of the cms probably wont like it to use

. is there a way to make this easier?

(p.s. the form posts in a database)

```
CODE (made it simple):
<form>
<textarea> $row['database_content']</textarea>
<input type='submit'>
</form>

and on the index page:
echo $row['database_content'];
```

problem is, 
if i make paragraphs in the textarea, and try to show it, it connects all the text so the paragraphs are gone. how can I fix that. I guess the database does the connection of the text?

Comment: `\n` should work for new lines or consider [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/).

Comment: You need to tell more details. Certainly empty lines can be coded. So the question is: what is your actual problem here?

Comment: Compare this example, there is no issue coding an empty line in textareas: https://jsfiddle.net/q6c393mv/ So most likely it is your code that somehow cripples the content you save and retrieve again. So again: post more details, _show your code_.

Comment: i want the user to be able to press return two times, just like word, so that will be the start of a new paragraph. without the need of tags. problem is, if you double tap return, the database connects all text and removes the empty lines

Comment: The database doesn't do that unless you have the wrong column datatype (e.g. VARCHAR).

Comment: Hi @thomagron, please consider reviewing the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section of this site to get better answers in the future. Thanks for asking your question on StackOverflow!

Comment: what datatype do I use instead of VARCHAR, i'm using that

Comment: @CharlotteDunois There is nothing in MySQL that disallows CRLF characters in VARCHAR datatype.

Comment: maybe i should make a button like 'new paragraph' and that automatically adds the <br> .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This always works for me with PHP and MYSQL, you just have to replace the `\n` character that does nothing in HTML with `<br>`.

You can either do this with the function:

`echo nl2br($string)`

If that doesn't work for some reason, try using a string replace:

`echo str_replace('\n', '<br>', $string);`